# Creating portable Bundles with extendable entities in Symfony2

Tags: inheritance, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to create some Symfony2 bundles which are reusable accross different projects, but where the entities also can be easily extended if required.

An example could be a reusable UserBundle, which contains a User entity with all the ORM mappings defined. In my application however, I might want to extend this entity and add extra columns, associations or override some of the parent's mappings.

The closest solution I could find are Doctrine2's mapped superclasses, but then I'd lose the plug-and-playness of my reusable bundle, I'd always have to extend the mapped superclass in my application even if I don't wish to modify the mappings.

The other documented inheritance schemes require modifying the parent's mappings, and then my UserBundle wouldn't be portable anymore accross projects.

Is there a way to define a fully-working entity in one bundle, and still extend that in another bundle?

Comment: +1 I have drawn the same conclusions as you, did you ever come up with a solution?

Comment: Nope, it seems it's not possible with the current inheritance models in Doctrine.

Comment: Any news on this problem ? I've been struggling with this limitation so many times that I wonder if a real fix will be issued at all. Forking bundles just to add a field in the entity mapping is getting old.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For future reference, this can be solved using [target entity resolution](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/cookbook/resolve-target-entity-listener.html).

You can find extra information in [Symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html).

The steps are pretty straighforward:

1. Create an interface in your bundle for the `User` entity

   ```
   namespace Acme/UserBundle/Model;
   interface UserInterface
   {
       // public functions expected for entity User
   }
   ```
2. Make your base `User` entity implement the interface

   ```
   namespace Acme/UserBundle/Entity;
   /**
    * @ORM\Entity
    */
   class User implements UserInterface
   {
       // implement public functions
   }
   ```
3. Create relationships as usual, but using the interface

   ```
   namespace Acme/InvoiceBundle/Entity;
   /**
    * @ORM\Entity
    */
   class Invoice
   {
       /**
        * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface")
        */
       protected $user;
   }
   ```
4. Configure the listener by adding the following to config.yml

   ```
   doctrine:
       # ....
       orm:
           # ....
           resolve_target_entities:
               Acme\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User
   ```

If you want to customize `User` entity for your current application

1. Extend from the `User` class or implement `UserInterface`

   ```
   namespace Acme/WebBundle/Entity;
   use Acme/UserBundle/Entity/User as BaseUser;
   /**
    * @ORM\Entity
    */
   class User extends BaseUser
   {
       // Add new fields and functions
   }
   ```
2. Configure the listener accordingly

   ```
   doctrine:
       # ....
       orm:
           # ....
           resolve_target_entities:
               Acme\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: Acme\WebBundle\Entity\User
   ```