# How to create an empty superclass with unknown subclasses for Doctrine in Symfony?

Tags: inheritance, symfony, doctrine-orm

As far as I understand if I want to use inheritance doctrine requires to list all subclasses in the supperclass mapping information.

The [manual](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance) states:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"person" = "Person", "employee" = "Employee"})
 */
class Person
{
    // ...
}
```

> The @InheritanceType, @DiscriminatorColumn and @DiscriminatorMap must
>   be specified on the topmost class that is part of the mapped entity
>   hierarchy.

As I'm developing a symfony bundle which will be reused by multiple applications, this is a major problem. I'd like to provide super classes which can be extended by the applications. This means the subclasses are not known at the time I implement the superclass.

Question [Creating portable Bundles with extendable entities in Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801173/creating-portable-bundles-with-extendable-entities-in-symfony2) is addressing the same problem.

The question here is: *What options do I have to come around this limitation?*

On of the areas I'm having this need is an order. An application should have the possibility to implement it's own order item subtypes. I came up with this solution, but that requires a lot of extra classes just to get something like inheritance.

http://www.gliffy.com/pubdoc/4293547/L.png

I'd be happy to see better/shorter solutions.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801173/creating-portable-bundles-with-extendable-entities-in-symfony2

Comment: Thanks! Did not find this. Added the inheritence tag to it, to make things more cler. Yes it's the same problem. However my question has an other scope. I KNOW that doctrine cannot handle this. My question is about what optoins do we have?