# Symfony2 Relationships using Interfaces results in duplicated table

Tags: symfony, inheritance, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to relate an entity in one bundle with another in another bundle to make the second one independent from the first one, and be able to reuse it.

I'm following [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html) documentation and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18782956/1209290) StackOverflows answer.

In the reusable bundle I have a Folder, File a that belongs to the folder and and interface like this:

```
namespace Acme\FolderBundle\Entity;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Folder implements FolderInterface
{
    // Has many files
}

namespace Acme\FolderBundle\Entity;

interface FolderInterface
{
    // no methods here
}

namespace Acme\FolderBundle\Entity;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class File
{
    // Belongs to one folder
}
```

And on the other bundle just one class:

```
namespace Acme\NewBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Acme\FolderBundle\Entity\Folder as BaseFolder;
use Acme\FolderBundle\Entity\FolderInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Folder extends BaseFolder implements FolderInterface
{
    // Has many files
}
```

And the config.yml's ORM configuration:

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
    auto_mapping: true
    resolve_target_entities:
        Acme\FolderBundle\Entity\FolderInterface: Acme\NewBundle\Entity\Folder
```

If I try to update my database schema, I get the following error:

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException]                                 
The table with name 'foldersDatabase.folder' already exists.
```

To get this working, I have to explicitly change one of the Folder's Entities table:

```
namespace Acme\FolderBundle\Entity;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="distributed_folder")
 */
class Folder implements FolderInterface
{
    // Has many files
}
```

Then, everything works but I get stuck with a table in my database (distributed_folder) that is never used.

Thanks a lot in advance!!

EDIT:
Fixed the annotation in the FolderInterface

Answer (score 1):

You can not make one entity extend another entity this way.
If you want to have an abstract class which contains the fields for two or more subclass entities, you should mark the abstract class as @ORM\MappedSuperclass , and make sure, it will not have the annotation @Entity. While on the subclasses , they each should have @Entity annotation , and @Table annotation with a unique name attribute.

Here is an example :

```
<?php

namespace Radsphere\MissionBundle\Model\Core\BaseAbstract;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 *
 * An abstract class implementation of mission
 */
 abstract class AbstractMission implements MissionInterface, IntegratedPluginInterface
 {
 /**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
  protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=36, unique=true)
 */
protected $guid;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
protected $title;


/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MissionTask", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="mtm_mission_task",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="mission_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="task_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")}
 *      )
 */
protected $tasks;


/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function addTask(MissionTaskInterface $missionTask)
{
    $this->getTasks()->add($missionTask);
    $missionTask->setMission($this);
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function setTasks(Collection $tasks)
{
    /** @var MissionTaskInterface $task */
    foreach ($tasks as $task) {
        $task->setMission($this);
    }

    $this->tasks = $tasks;
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function getTasks()
{
    $tasks = $this->tasks;
    foreach ($tasks as $task) {
        if ($task instanceof MissionTaskInterface) {
            if (!$task->getIsEnabled()) {
                /** @var $tasks Collection */
                $tasks->removeElement($task);
            }
        }
    }

    return $tasks;
}


}
```

and the entity itself:

```
   <?php

   namespace Radsphere\MissionBundle\Entity;

   use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
   use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
   use Radsphere\MissionBundle\Model\Core\BaseAbstract\AbstractMission;

   /**
   * Mission entity
   *
   * @ORM\Table(name="mission_bundle_mission", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="guid_idx",      columns={"guid"})})
   * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
   * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MissionRepository")
   */
   class Mission extends AbstractMission
   {
   /**
    * Constructor
   */
   public function __construct()
   {

      $this->tasks = new ArrayCollection();
   }
 }
```

Comment: I can't use @ORM\MappedSuperclass because the parent class Acme\FolderBundle\Entity\Folder has many files, and that is not allowed with your solution. Also, if that were the case, I wouldn't see the point for defining relationships with an interface ([docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html)). In that tutorial, the interface has a many-to-one relationship with either Customer or BaseCustomer, then both are entities because the bundles can be used by themselves or with others (stated at the final thoughts section).

Comment: You may use Relations in the abstract class,But the reference itself will be to the entity.

Comment: From your code, I understand that MissionTask Entity will have a many-to-one relation to Mission (correct me if I'm wrong). If that is the case, the bundles are not detached, and cannot be reused easily: if in another project I want to use the FolderBundle I will have to edit the Folder class Acme\FolderBundle\Entity\Folder (MissionTask Entity in your example).

Comment: Then you can use OneToMany Unidirectional with @ManyToMany annotation

Comment: Thanks for the answer shacharsol, but it is not exactly what I answered so I can't accept it. I still don't understand why this doesn't work even if the [symfony2 docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html) say that it should.