# Create bundle with extendable entities

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to create a bundle where all entities can be replaceable/extendable and came across these two pages:

- [Creating portable Bundles with extendable entities in Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801173/creating-portable-bundles-with-extendable-entities-in-symfony2)
- https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html

Now I'm trying to put it into practice for the first time, and created this simple test:

In the bundle, I created an interface for the Country entity

```php
namespace My\Custom\Bundle\Entity;

interface CountryInterface
{
    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getIsoCode(): ?string;
}
```

Then, I created the entity itself

```php
namespace My\Custom\Bundle\Entity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Country implements CountryInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $isoCode;

    // getters/setters
}
```

And in my application I tried this to extend the entity:

```php
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use My\Custom\Bundle\Entity\Country as BaseCountry;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Country extends BaseCountry
{
    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $name;
}
```

Then I added this in my doctrine configuration:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        resolve_target_entities:
            My\Custom\Bundle\CountryInterface: App\Entity\Country
```

But when doing `doctrine:migrations:diff` I always get an error saying  `The table with name 'my_custom_bundle.country' already exists.`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably need to tweak your orm mapping to exclude the base Country class.

Comment: The thing is that I don't actually want to exclude the base class. The bundle's entities should be the default ones, **except** if they are extended... Turning them into mapped superclasses doesn't solve this either, because when installing the bundle you'd have to extend every superclass in you application, even if you don't wish to modify it.

Sylius seems to work that way, but I can't seem to figure out how they get it done :-)

Comment: The target resolver functionality is really about relations and not about replacing one class with another.  I don't know anyway to tell doctrine to use an entity unless it has been extended by another.  And the error of course comes from the fact that you can't have two entities pointing to the same table.  Never really dug into Sylius.  I know it is complicated.  They probably have a chat channel somewhere.